# Pandas convert dataframe to dictionary with unique keys as (index,col) from the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table

```
data = {'id':[1,2,3],'a':[4,5,6],'b':[7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('id')
```

[image]

---

I want to generate the output by converting this dataframe into a `dict` such that each unique `(index,column)` is the key in the dictionary and its corresponding cell is the value. The key is a string delimited by a underscore "_".

The output is as follows for this toy example

```
output_dict = {
    1_a:4,
    2_a:5,
    3_a:5,
    1_b:7,
    2_b:8,
    3_b:9,
}
```

---

So far I have tried `pd.pivot`. I have also tried to create a multindex using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` but I cannot seem to get the dataframe to have just one column with the correct values. I am able to create the correct index pairs but am not able to get the correct corresponding values.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I am looking for a vectorized pandas approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack` to reshape the dataframe into a multiindex series followed by `to_dict` to create dictionary

```
df.stack().to_dict()
```

---

```
{(1, 'a'): 4, (1, 'b'): 7, (2, 'a'): 5, (2, 'b'): 8, (3, 'a'): 6, (3, 'b'): 9}
```

To flatten the multiindex

```
s = df.stack()
s.index = ['{}_{}'.format(*t) for t in s.index]
s.to_dict()
```

---

```
{'1_a': 4, '1_b': 7, '2_a': 5, '2_b': 8, '3_a': 6, '3_b': 9}
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to understand the ```stack```. Is it mainly used for this purpose or are there any other applications of it as well?

Comment: @dracarys There are many more applications of  `stack` but basically it is used  reshape the dataframe i.e stack one or more column levels into a multilevel index creating a multiindex series/dataframe. You can also check [`this reshaping guide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) to learn more about stack

Comment: I would actually like to convert to JSON, I know it can be done using ```to_json()```. I tried and it works, but is there a easy way of converting the keys to a string like ```1_a,1_b,...2_a``` instead of tuples

Comment: Yes we can flatten the MultiIndex. Lemme edit the answer.

Comment: Ill edit the question to include that, sorry I realized that later